# tearDown() is not called after script execution from console

Tags: java, junit, jmeter, teardown

I have JMeter script which tests REST API.

It is configured with [Junit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.html):

[image]

During the test, I am posting a lot of items. I want to clean up DB after test execution. I put appropriate logic to `tearDown()`.

However, I found that execution from console doesn't call `teaDown()`!

Launching from UI works fine.

Here is implementation for `tearDown()`:

```
@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
    LOG.info("tearDown() called");
    deleteRecordingsFromDb();

    SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdown();
    if (client != null && !client.isClosed()) {
        client.close();
    }
    minClient = null;
}
```

Also, be aware that [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) is used. And parameter is passed with `-Jload-profiles="..."`

***How to make tearDown() executable from the console?***

Comment: how do you run via console? and does the teardown never gets executed using the command line?

Comment: it may sound trivial or even slightly silly - but are you sure you run your tests in non-gui on the SAME JMeter instance as you do in GUI mode?

Comment: @Yuri I definitely sure about it.JMeter is exactly the same. Project is packed to one fat jar and loaded to `/jmeter-home/lib/ext/junit`. However, on UI mode I run without shaping timer. I am using loops counter.

Comment: @nullpointer I can post full command later. For now it is like `-jar /jmeter-home/bin/jmeter.jar -J... -n -t my-load.jmx`. Looks like yes, it is always skipped. Because DB is over loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making some mistakes:

- You want to call a method that you annotated with @AfterClass but you don't have a method annotated with @Test. So JMeter will not even discover your method.
- JMeter will automatically call setup (@BeforeClass) and tearDown(@AfterClass) methods within an execution of an method annotated with @Test unless you uncheck them

So if you want to make a cleanup for the whole test, just put your code in a regular JSR223 Sampler using Groovy code for example, no need for JUnit request for that.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler

Comment: Screen shot contains only teardown thread group. Of course suite has bunch of tests, and setUp(). Problem is that I have all stuff, like BeforeClass, AfterClass and Test. I see at log that set Up() is called, whereas tearDown() is skipped.

Comment: Hello, my answer is still valid after your comment

Comment: I will try it on Monday, and let you know the result. I want to add that `setUp()` I am using for initialization for Concurrent queue during posting new items they are also stored in a queue. When `tearDown` is called I am going through all queue and deleting them. With your variant, it wouldn't be so easy.